# Delete all rows with partial match string Excel 2007

Tags: excel

I have a large column of data and many rows that are similar (page 1 of 100, page 2 of 100).  What's the best way to delete all of the rows that contain the text 'page'?

Comment: you can try VBA. You can record a macro and adapt the code. Note that if you parse and delete rows, you should do it from bottom to top.

Answer (score 1):

select the range `sort & filter - filter - text filters - contains - "page" - OK`
Make your selection and hit delete, then `filter - clear filter from`
This will delete everything with the text filter you supplied

Answer (score 0):

I often solve these types of data transformation problems with a plain text editor.
For example, if you paste your table into Vim, you can process it with something like `:g/page/d`, then paste it back into Excel.